# Android+Java:File deletion error

Tags: java, android, file

hi 
 i 've following code. and i want to delete a zip folder from a particular path

```
   File file = new File("/mibook/"+mFilename+"/"+mZipname.toString());
   boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

but it returns False. why? TIA
edit:
For file also this code not working

```
 file = new File("/mibook/"+mFilename+"/iphone_settings.css");
```

Comment: First make sure whether file exist or not.

Comment: Prblm Solved for file: i gave full path starting from /mnt. but why it is like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete folders that still have content in it that way. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) says: "Directories must be empty before they will be deleted." Try to delete it [recursively](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0483.html).

Comment: if i give full path for recursive function, do it delete all the file from parent? if so i dont want to try it..

Comment: Ahh - you want to delete a file which does not exist. I guess the directory /mibook/... does not exist on your device. Remember that you are on a Linux operating system where "/" points to the root directory. You definitely want to find out the directory to the external storage this way: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29